# Define maintenance windows in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to define periods of time where the scheduler will not mark tasks as ready.
For example, I have a DAG with a lengthy backfill period.  The execution of the backfill will run throughout the day until the DAG is caught up.  However I do not want and executions of the DAG to execute between midnight and 2 am.
Is it possible to achieve this through configuration?